# How can I use mcp2515 & device tree?

Tags: linux-device-driver, spi, can-bus, device-tree

My Kernel Source writes platform data to device tree.(kernel version 3.10.9)

The board used is Exynos5422.

So I wrote mcp2515 platform data parameter to .dts

**dts:**

```
spi_1: spi@12d30000 {

            status = "okay";
            spi-src-clk = <0>;
            num-cs = <1>;
            gpios = <&gpa2 4 0>,
                    <&gpa2 6 0>,
                    <&gpa2 7 0>;

            can1: mcp251x@0{
                    compatible ="microchip,mcp2515";
                    reg = <0>;
                    spi-max-frequency = <2000000>;
                    pinctrl-names = "default";
                    pinctr-0=<&mcp_irq>;
                    interrupts = < 0 0 0 >;
                    interrupt-parent = <&gpx1>;
                    irq_gpio = <&gpx1 5 0>;
                    reset_gpio = <&gph0 1 0>;
                    controller-data {
                            cs-gpio = <&gpa2 5 0>;
                            samsung,spi-feedback-delay = <0>;
                     };
            };

 };

 mcp_irq: mcp_irq {
                    samsung,pins = "gpx1-5";
                    samsung,pin-function = <0xf>;
                    samsung,pin-pud = <3>;
                    samsung,pin-drv = <3>;

};
```

When the following assignment fails, pdata is null, resulting in fatal error below.

struct mcp251x_platform_data *pdata = spi->dev.platform_data

**mcp251x.c:**

```
if (!pdata) {
    /* Platform data is required for osc freq */
    goto error_out;

}
```

**Settings:**

[image]

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps, use of newer kernel will help you. Besides that did you indeed mean **pinctr**?

Comment: I changed mcp251x driver to 3.14 version. Then Another error has occurred. "mcp251x spi1.0: MCP251x didn't enter in conf mode after reset. ". So I tested spidev_test program. As a result I guess that spi pins are not setting. Does SPI of s3c64xx series type need any other settings?